# how to equalize length of blocks of a column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

hii experts i have a file like as given below i want to equalize the all block of column separated by > symbol based on highest length of the block by appending zero at the end as given in expected answer.Thanks.

```
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
>
3 4 5
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
```

expected output

```
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
0 0 0
>
3 4 5
0 0 0
0 0 0
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
```

Comment: Are all the records of the same length, though?

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: please help sir...unable to to it

Comment: output should be of equal length....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting `RS` and `FS` you can treat each block as a single record, and each line as one field. This awk takes two passes through the data, hence you need to list the file twice. The first pass computes the max number of lines, the second pass fills in with extra lines where necessary.

Note that because the file begins with a separator, awk sees an initial empty record that we don't care about. That's why we test for `FNR > 1` on the second pass.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { RS=">"; OFS=FS="\n" }
NR == FNR { if (NF > max) max = NF; next }
FNR > 1 { for (i=NF; i<max; ++i) { $i = "0 0 0" } print RS $0 }
' file file
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
0 0 0
>
3 4 5
0 0 0
0 0 0
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
```

Comment: but i get gaps after each block how to remove it

Comment: Is it possible you have DOS (CR/LF) line endings? Do you see any `^M` characters if you do `cat -v file` on your input?

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following, this solution should work with any `awk`(though I tested with GNU `awk` only). Also this will look for maximum field number in whole Input_file and will print zeros as per that + it will add lines too as per maximum number of lines found in any block.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^>/){
     maxBlock=(maxBlock>count?maxBlock:count)
  }
  else{
     count++
  }
  maxField=(maxField>NF?maxField:NF)
  next
}
/^>/{
  if(FNR>1 && (count1<maxBlock)){
     while(++count1<=maxBlock){
        zeros=sprintf("%0"maxField"d","0")
        gsub(/./,"& ",zeros)
        print zeros
     }
  }
  print
  count1=zeros=""
  next
}
{
  print
  count1++
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** More generic solution, will print zeros as per blocks maximum lines + it will add zeros into existing lines too in case their field length is lesser than highest field length found in Input_file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^>/){
    maxBlock=(maxBlock>count?maxBlock:count)
  }
  else{
    count++
  }
  maxField=(maxField>NF?maxField:NF)
  next
}
/^>/{
  if(FNR>1 && (count1<maxBlock)){
    while(++count1<=maxBlock){
      zeros=sprintf("%0"maxField"d","0")
      gsub(/./,"& ",zeros)
      print zeros
    }
  }
  print
  count1=zeros=""
  next
}
{
  if(NF<maxField){
    zeros=sprintf("%0"maxField-NF"d","0")
    gsub(/./,"& ",zeros)
    $0=$0 OFS zeros
  }
  print
  count1++
  zeros=""
}
' Input_file  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

One for GNU awk. It uses `split`'s 4th parameter for storing `FS`es - and `RT` since I'm already using GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -v RS=">" '                    # record separator
NR==FNR {
    if(nf<NF) {                       # get the largest record (longest?, NFstest?)
        nf=NF
        p=$0
    }
    next
}
{
    if(FNR==1)                        # skip the first empty record
        split(p,t,FS,seps)            # good time to get record structure to seps
    else {
        print rt                      # print previous RT
        for(i=1;i<=nf;i++)            # loop current fields
            printf "%d%s",$i,seps[i]  # output with proto structure seps
    }
    rt=RT                             # RT for next round
}' file file
```

Output:

```
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
0 0 0
>
3 4 5
0 0 0
0 0 0
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl that will do the whole thing in one pass over the file:

```
$ perl -0777 -nE '@arr=/(?<=^>$)([^>]+)/gm;
                for (@arr) {
                    $x=split(/\r?\n/);
                    $max=$x if $x>$max;
                }   
                for (@arr) {
                    @sa=split(/\r?\n/);
                    for (scalar @sa .. $max-1) {push @sa, "0 0 0";}
                    print ">"; say join("\n", @sa);
                }' file
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
0 0 0
>
3 4 5
0 0 0
0 0 0
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl and awk combination.

Input file

```
$ cat equal_block.txt
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
>
3 4 5
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
$
```

Getting the max using Perl

```
$ max=$(perl -0777 -ne ' { while( />([^>]+)/gmos ) { $c=split("\n",$1);if($c-1>$maxc) { $maxc=$c-1 }}  print "$maxc\n"  } ' equal_block.txt)
$ echo $max
3
$
```

Now pass the max to another awk

```
$ awk  -v max=$max '{  print ; m2=/^>/?max:max-1; for(i=1;i<=m2;i++) { getline; if($0~/^>/) { for(j=i;j<=m2;j++) { print "0 0 0"; }  print; next }  print $0  } }  ' equal_block.txt
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
0 0 0
>
3 4 5
0 0 0
0 0 0
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
$
```

Assuming the input file has 3 columns, then below also would work.

```
$  perl -ne ' chomp; if(/^>/) { print "\n$_ " } else { print "$_ " } ' equal_block.txt  | awk  -v max=$max ' BEGIN{OFS=" " } NF>0{ print $1; for(i=2;i<=3*max;i=i+3) { print $i+0,$(i+1)+0,$(i+2)+0 } } '
>
1 2 3
3 4 5
0 0 0
>
3 4 5
0 0 0
0 0 0
>
2 3 4
3 4 5
3 4 5
$
```